# What is the String equivalent of += in numeric data forms?

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, logic

I have a code that is:

```
String str = "hi";
String[] strArray = new String[5];
for(int c = 0;c < 5;c++){
    str += strArray[c];
}
```

Although with 5 strings I can do one by one? but what if there are 50, or even 5 hundred? This type of += gave me an error, so how do I add up all the strings in the array properly?

Comment: What error? It should be working with 5 or with 50.

Comment: Strings are immutable, meaning their content cannot change. Try using the StringBuilder class.

Comment: @user3352495 the literal string stored in the string pool can't change, but the variable is not final, so it can get reassigned.

Comment: @zbz.lvlv *what is the error?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `+=` on `String` objects use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Reason being in JAVA appending string creates immutable String objects each time which leads to memory explosion. On the other hand, `StringBuilder` is mutable object, you append to your heart's content & then return a `String` object.

```
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String[] strArray = new String[5]; //or some big number
    for(int c = 0;c < 5;c++)
    {
        stringBuilder.append(strArray[c]);
    }
    System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what error you got - I ran your example an it works fine.
If you print the resulting `str` though, you get `hinullnullnullnullnull` because you haven't put anything in the `strArray` yet.

String concatenation with the `+=` operator is not efficient in Java: to do this efficiently, you need to use the `StringBuilder` class.

Example of how to do that with the `StringBuilder` class:

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String[] strArray = new String[50];
    // Put something in the strings in strArray
    for (int c = 0; c < strArray.length; c++) {
        builder.append(strArray[c]);
    }
    String str = builder.toString();
```

Comment: I think they optimized that away a while ago. See [1]
Now, you can do string concatenation and internally, the StringBuilder will be used.
[1]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927630/java-string-concat-vs-stringbuilder-optimised-so-what-should-i-do

Comment: I think that you read the answer to that question wrong. The accepted answer actually says to *use* `StringBuilder` rather than concatenating using the `+` operator - if you're doing it in a loop, like the OP is asking.