# What is the efficient way to update a String?

Tags: java, string, performance

Assuming that I need to initiate a String and then update it for a couple a times more, like in this pseudo code:

```
String s = "first";
if (<some condition>) { s += "second"; }
if (<some condition>) { s += "third"; }
if (<some condition>) { s += "fourth"; }
```

In case that I have about 4 times in maximum, is it better to use it that way or just simply use StringBuffer/StringBuilder ?

Actually what i'm asking is, in case of which updating times of a String (which is a mutable type) is the efficient way to use the above options?

Comment: I would recommend StringBuilder.  But if you're only doing this 4 times...  Performance might not be that much of an issue anyway.

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, String is not a mutable class. Every time you use `+=`, another object is returned.

Second, unless you use that in a tight loop, it is not very important anyway.

Third, although it may not be a computer science-like approach, if I try to use

```
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("first");
    s.append( "second" );
    s.append( "third" );
    s.append( "fourth" );
```

Intellij suggests to replace it with a String, and that suggestion only appears if it is at least as efficient to use a simple String (although it may not be exactly the same thing because of the conditions)

According to [Java: String concat vs StringBuilder - optimised, so what should I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927630/java-string-concat-vs-stringbuilder-optimised-so-what-should-i-do/14927864#14927864)
the Java compiler does replace a series of String concatenations with String builders:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "first";

    s+=" second" ;
    if(args.length >0)
    s+=" third";

    System.out.println("s, = " + s);
}
```

Using JDK 1.8.0_66 and using `javap -c SbTest.class` the following output is produced. Although I am not an expert on byte code, it seems that multiple instances of `StringBuilder` are created (`3`,`28`). So as suggested in the linked answers, the compiled code seems to be something like:

```
    String s = "first";
    s = new StringBuilder().append(s).append(" second") ;
    if(args.length >0)
        s = new StringBuilder().append(s).append(" third") ;
```

So unless the JIT is optimizing this, it might still be more efficient to use the `StringBuilder` yourself.

```
 public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2                  // String first
       2: astore_1
       3: new           #3                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
       6: dup
       7: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      10: aload_1
      11: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      14: ldc           #6                  // String  second
      16: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      19: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      22: astore_1
      23: aload_0
      24: arraylength
      25: ifle          48
      28: new           #3                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
      31: dup
      32: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      35: aload_1
      36: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      39: ldc           #8                  // String  third
      41: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      44: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      47: astore_1
      48: getstatic     #9                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      51: new           #3                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
      54: dup
      55: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
      58: ldc           #10                 // String s, =
      60: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      63: aload_1
      64: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
      67: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
      70: invokevirtual #11                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      73: return
```

Comment: Compiler does that for you, see Igoranze answer.

Comment: @ctomek: well but it seems to create multiple StringBuilders for that, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "first";
if (<some condition>) { s += "second"; }
if (<some condition>) { s += "third"; }
if (<some condition>) { s += "fourth"; }
```

Is the right approach because the compiler will [turn it into a StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)
(*JDK 1.6 and above*)
That said, the optimization is the same unless you are using it inside a loop.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14927864/4985572) for more info

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with reasonably sized strings (like the words you have there) using the string class is completely fine, and using a string builder class won't be much faster than using a normal string.  You want to replace it when you might be dealing with huge strings (think many many paragraphs) and repeatedly changing them.  StringBuilder and StringBuffer should work about the same, but StringBuffer is thread safe, so if you are going to write multithreaded code then use StringBuffer.

Comment: Compiler does that for you, see Igoranze answer.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to know is to benchmark.

```
package com.example;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ExampleTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            Instant start = Instant.now();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {

                // Try various implementations here...
                String s = "first";
                if (true) {
                    s += "second";
                }
                if (true) {
                    s += "third";
                }
                if (true) {
                    s += "fourth";
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Took: " + Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis() + " millis");
        }
    }

}
```

If performance turns out not to be an issue then optimise for the human and make it as readable and maintainable as possible.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java for how to write a microbenchmark in java

Comment: I'd argue that applying those 8 rules for the purposes of answering this question would be overkill, and that with all things being equal this would prove whether one implementation was significantly faster than another. If the performance of two implementations is roughly equal according to the above then yeah perhaps taking a more in-depth look would be appropriate.

Of course I totally agree that this template should not be used as a general guide for benchmarking.