# How to prepend "\n" to the last word of String?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I want to prepend "\n" to the last word of the string
for example

`Hello friends 123`

Here i want to add "\n" just before the word "123"

I tried below code but having no idea what to do now

```
String sentence  = "I am Mahesh 123"
String[] parts = sentence.split(" ");
String lastWord = "\n" + parts[parts.length - 1];
```

Comment: as what trouble are you facing?

Comment: Maybe something like [`s = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf(" ")+1) + "\n" + s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);`](http://ideone.com/hgBX6Y)? What is the output you are trying to get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
      Try this
            String sentence  = "Hello friends 123456";
            String[] parts = sentence.split(" ");
            parts[parts.length - 1] = "\n" + parts[parts.length - 1];

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String part : parts) {
                builder.append(part);
                builder.append(" ");
            }

            System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Output will be :~

```
 Hello friends

 123456
```

Comment: Also inserts a space at the end of the string. And it trims the end of the string (it'd replace multiple spaces at the end with a single space). And it creates lots of unnecessary strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code...it will work

```
parts[parts.length]=parts[parts.length-1];
parts[parts.length-1]="\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
String sentence  = "I am Mahesh 123";
        String[] parts = sentence.split(" ");
        String string="";
        for (int i =0;i<parts.length;i++)
        {
            if (i==parts.length-1)
            {
                string = string+"\n"+parts[i];
            }
            else
            string = string+" "+parts[i];

        }
        Toast.makeText(Help.this, string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a break/new line at the end of your string.
You can find the space via `lastIndexOf()`, this will give you the `int` of where the space is located in the `String sentence`.
You can use this small example here:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence =  "I am Mahesh 123";
        int locationOfLastSpace = sentence.lastIndexOf(' ');

        String result = sentence.substring(0, locationOfLastSpace) //before the last word
            + "\n" 
            + sentence.substring(locationOfLastSpace).trim(); //the last word, trim just removes the spaces

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Note that `StringBuilder` is not used because since [Java 1.6 the compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38142143/4985572) will create s `StringBuilder` for you